# Alignment inside a Row

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I'm trying to space this two items inside a row, I need to fix the text on the center and the icon in the right in the Row, but it's not working.

[Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fH9um.jpg) is the image of how looks now

Here is the current code

```
Row(
   mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
   children: <Widget>[
     myText(text, FontWeight.w700, Colors.white),
     Icon(Icons.arrow_drop_down,color: Colors.white),  
   ],
 );
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This [Medium post](https://medium.com/flutter-community/flutter-layout-cheat-sheet-5363348d037e) is a cheat sheet for layouts in Flutter. Under the paragraph **Expanded** an attribute called `flex` is explained.

Play around with flex, but this example should get you going:

```
Row(
  children: <Widget>[
    Expanded(
      child: Container(),
      flex: 1,
    ),
    Expanded(
      child: myText(text, FontWeight.w700, Colors.white),
      flex: 2,
    ),
    Expanded(
      child: Icon(Icons.arrow_drop_down,color: Colors.white),  
      flex: 1,
    ),
  ],
),
```